# Delegate.Combine: How to Check if multicast (combinable) delegates already has a delegate inside of it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, concatenation, multicastdelegate

I am using Unity 3D, however, that information should be irrelevant for solving this problem as the core problem is System.Delegate (I wanted to let you know as I'll be linking to some Unity docs for clarification).

I have a custom window that has a custom update function `DirectorUpdate`. I need this function to run every editor update regardless of what the user/window is doing.

In order for this to be called every editor update, I Combine my method with the Delegate [EditorApplication.update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-update.html):

```
protected void OnEnable()
{
    // If I do the below, base EditorApplication.update won't be called anymore.
    // EditorApplication.update = this.DirectorUpdate;
    // So I need to do this:
    EditorApplication.update = (EditorApplication.CallbackFunction)System.Delegate.Combine(new EditorApplication.CallbackFunction(this.DirectorUpdate), EditorApplication.update);

    ... // Other stuff
}
```

Note that this is done inside a window's [OnEnable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.OnEnable.html).

**The problem is that OnEnable can be called more than once during a single run** (for example, when closing the window and then reopening the window during a single editor session) **causing**

`EditorApplication.update = (EditorApplication.CallbackFunction)System.Delegate.Combine(new EditorApplication.CallbackFunction(this.DirectorUpdate), EditorApplication.update);`

**to be called multiple times,** meaning my update method `(this.DirectorUpdate)` will eventually get called multiple times per update, which is causing some serious bugs.

**So,** *the question is* how do I check if `EditorApplication.update` already has my method "inside" of it. (By inside of it, I of course mean it has already been `System.Delegate.Combine(d)` to the delegate.)

I am aware that there could be other solutions, for example restoring EditorApplication.update to what it was prior when the window closes, however that won't account for all situations (for example, OnEnable also gets called during window refresh and such) and the bug will persist. (Also, what if another window Concatenates with EditorApplication.update while this window is open?) As such, the best solution would be to check if EditorApplication.update is already callin this method BEFORE Delegate.Combine-ing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you took the complicated road ;)

Subscribing and unsubscribing events and delegates is as simple as using the operators [`+=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#delegate-combination) and [`-=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/subtraction-operator#delegate-removal) like

```
protected void OnEnable()
{
    // You can substract your callback even though it wasn't added so far
    // This makes sure it is definitely only added once (for this instance)
    EditorApplication.update -= DirectorUpdate;
    
    // This basically internally does such a Combine for you
    EditorApplication.update += DirectorUpdate;
    
    ... // Other stuff
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    // Remove the callback once not needed anymore
    EditorApplication.update -= DirectorUpdate;
}
```

This way you can also have multiple instances of this window open and they all will receive the callback individually.

---

Btw if this is actually about an [`EditorWindow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) then afaik you should not use `OnEnabled` but you would rather use `Awake`

> Called as the new window is opened.

and `OnDestroy`.

Comment: Dang, I was super hopeful for this answer; however, I just tested it and it doesn't seem to be working: after closing & reopening the window the bug persists. Also, JetBrains rider is giving me this warning: "Delegate subtraction has unpredictable result".

Comment: Excuse my last comment - it does appear to be working! (I made a minor mistake) However, it seems that the OnDisable() part is absolutely necessary for it to work (I guess because otherwise the old window's "instance" isn't removed om delegate subtraction). I'm going to test this further and report back, probably going to give this answer the checkmark :)

Comment: @danglingPointer exactly ;) as said always remove callbacks once not needed anymore. If the window is closed but you don't remove the callback you will get NullReferenceExceptions since it will still try to call the instanced method from an object that doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with what `System.Delegate.Combine(d)` does, but you can consider instead of enabling/disabling your window, destroying and instantiating it every time, and move your code to the `Start` or the `Awake` for it to be called only once per window "activation".

Last but not least, use a mighty boolean in the `OnDisable` so that you can handle the combine execution if your component was ever disabled. Like so:

```
bool omgIWasDisabled;
protected void OnEnable()
{
    if (!omgIWasDisabled) {
        EditorApplication.update = (EditorApplication.CallbackFunction)System.Delegate.Combine(new EditorApplication.CallbackFunction(this.DirectorUpdate), EditorApplication.update);
    }
   
    ... // Other stuff
}  

void OnDisable() {
    omgIWasDisabled = true;
}
```

Hope any of those works out.

Comment: You can make this slightly simpler by making the bool 'omgIWasAdded' static and have it set true right after the main code in OnEnable() (and not have to deal with OnDisable()), anyhow I thought of this solution and it very well might be what I got with.